# Retornar Collection de Produtos de acordo a Categoria

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Pessoal não estou conseguindo trazer a lista de produtos que tenha pelo menos 1 categoria relacionada.

```
//Classe

public class EventoConfiguracaoViewModel
    {

        public EventoConfiguracaoViewModel()
        {

            Menus = new List<MenuViewModel>();
            Categorias = new List<CategoriaViewModel>();
            Produtos = new List<ProdutoViewModel>();
            CupomDescontos = new List<CupomDesconto>();
            MenuLaterais =new List<MenuLateralViewModel>();
        }

        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public int CdEvento { get; set; }
        public virtual EventoViewModel Evento { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<MenuViewModel> Menus { get; set; }
        public ICollection<MenuLateralViewModel> MenuLaterais { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<CategoriaViewModel> Categorias { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ProdutoViewModel> Produtos { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<CupomDesconto> CupomDescontos { get; set; }
    }
```

Fiz dessa forma e não funcionou:

```
 public ActionResult ObterProdutoPorCategoria(int? id, string categoria, int? clienteId, int? cdEvento, string tema)
        {

            ViewBag.Tema = tema;
            var configuracao = _eventoConfiguracaoAppService.ObterTodosEventoConfiguracaosDoClientes(clienteId.Value,
                cdEvento.Value);

            var retv = configuracao.Where(e => e.Produtos.Any(p => p.CategoriaId == 2));

            return View(retv);


        }
```

Comment: Por favor, tente ser mais específico. Clique em [edit] e dê mais detalhes. É impossível te ajudar sem saber do que você está falando.

Comment: Como não estou sendo específico já. Informei no texto: 
"Pessoal não estou conseguindo trazer a lista de produtos que tenha pelo menos 1 categoria relacionada."

Comment: Em vez de print, coloque o código que fica muito mais fácil a leitura. Acredito que seja necessário apenas a estrutura da classe Configuração e Produto, e o código que você está usando hoje para realizar o filtro

Comment: Pronto... Coloquei o código

Comment: A view recebe qual modelo?

Comment: Recebe um IEnumerable<EventoConfiguracaoViewModel>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elaborei uma resposta que com base no que você colocou....

Criei toda uma estrutura para ficar mais facil de desenvolver
Basicamente o que você precisa é desta linha, para retornar a lista de produtos com a categoria desejada

```
var idEquals1 = c.Where(e => e.Produtos != null && e.Produtos.Any(pe => pe.CategoriaId.Equals(2))).Select(a=> new Config{Produtos = a.Produtos.Where(p=>p.CategoriaId == 2).ToList()}).ToList();
```

Segue o código do programa para teste

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<Produto> p = new List<Produto>();
        List<Config> c = new List<Config>();

        var cat1 = new Categoria { Id = 1, Desc = "Categoria 1" };
        var cat2 = new Categoria { Id = 2, Desc = "Categoria 2" };

        for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
        {
            if (i % 2 == 0)
                p.Add(new Produto { Id = i, CategoriaId = 2, Desc = "produto " + i });
            else
                p.Add(new Produto { Id = i, CategoriaId = 1, Desc = "produto " + i });
        }

        c.Add(new Config { Produtos = prod });
        c.Add(new Config());


        var idEquals1 = c.Where(e => e.Produtos != null && e.Produtos.Any(pe => pe.CategoriaId.Equals(2))).Select(a=> new Config{Produtos = a.Produtos.Where(p=>p.CategoriaId == 2).ToList()}).ToList();


    }
}



public class Config
{

    public List<Produto> Produtos { get; set; }
}

public class Categoria
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Desc { get; set; }

}


public class Produto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CategoriaId { get; set; }
    public string Desc { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Nesse caso ele vai retornar um objeto de Produto, mas não seria isso, gostaria que ele só retornasse EventoConfiguracao com só os produtos filtrados pela categoria que determinei 
 var retv = configuracao.Where(e => e.Produtos.Any(p => p.CategoriaId == 2));

Comment: Editei a resposta agora acho que resolve seu problema

Comment: você so precisa preencher o novo objeto EventoConfiguracao

Comment: Ok vou tentar obrigado

Comment: Marco você é  o cara ... deu certo aqui mutíssimo obrigado pela atenção ... salvou a pátria.. era justamente isso ai